# FormGroup is returning the last active form object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I'm am working on dynamic forms, with formly on angular Typescript, the formGroup displays correctly all the time, but initially the current form is console log correctly, but when I click on another form it returns the last active form.

The form is displayed on the screen by being subscribed and if there is a menu click it displays the form.

I have tried asynchronous checks and adding a timer to make sure the form is ready, unsubscribe and resubscribing.